# Multiple Thread groups in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, threadgroup

I am using jMeter for my testing script. I need 3 thread groups as 3 users will login and will read 3 different lines from a CSV file. My thread groups should not start consecutively or concurrently. They should start after some delays between them.

I added flow control action (for delay) before my login request but the delays are not working properly i.e., all thread start simultaneously most of the time.

Can anyone please suggest me any better option for delays between login actions in my different thread groups?

Answer (score 0):

> I need 3 Thread groups as 3 users will Login

this is wrong as different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) should be used when you simulate different groups of business users (which are doing different stuff), if all users are doing the same (apart from data coming from the CSV file) it makes sense to use single Thread Group with 3 threads (virtual users)

The "delay" between first and second user, second and third, etc. can be configured via [ramp-up period setting](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide/), few examples:

- 3 users, 3 seconds ramp-up - 1 second delay between arrivals
- 3 users, 6 seconds ramp-up - 2 seconds delay between artivals
- etc.

Comment: Actually my thread groups are communicating with each other.All 3 different users are performing different functions e.g., if thread group 1 uses an API to perform something the other thread uses another API in response to that request and perform the operation like make call and answer call etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Inter-Thread Communication plugin to send data between ThreadsGroups (https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/ )?

Comment: Thabks for your  answer but my question was related to delay between thread groups  not to send data between thread groups.

Comment: I meant the implementation of the delay with this data transfer mechanism. You just send the signal from group_1 (signal sending is in preprocessor). That signal is received in waiting group_2 which will start then (You can add timer also in group_2). Unless I interpret something of your question differently :)